# How to toggle React component with Redux using hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I am trying to toggle (show/hide) react component with redux but I am getting an error:

```
Error: An error occurred while selecting the store state.
```

This error disappears when I access state with direct call.

change this:

```
const show = useSelector(state => state.toggle[id]);
```

to this:

```
const show = useSelector(state => state.empty);
```

#### Toggle component

```
import React from 'react';
import {useSelector} from 'react-redux';


export const Toggle = ({id, children}) => {
  const show = useSelector(state => state.toggles[id]);
  return show ? children : null;
};
```

#### Reducer

```
const initialState = {
  empty: false
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SHOW':
      return {...state, [action.payload]: true};
    case 'HIDE':
      return {...state, [action.payload]: false};
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

#### Actions

```
export const showToggle = id => ({type: 'SHOW', payload: id});
export const hideToggle = id => ({type: 'HIDE', payload: id});
```

#### Child Component

```
import React from 'react';

export const MyComponent = ({onClick}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      Do something awesome here
      <button onClick={onClick}>Ok</button>
    </div>
  )
};
```

#### Main Component

```
import React from 'react';
import {useDispatch} from 'react-redux';
import {Toggle} from './Toggle';
import {MyComponent} from './MyComponent';
import {showToggle, hideToggle} from './actions';

export const SomeOtherComponent = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const toggleId = 'empty';
  return (
    <div>
            <span>Say something<span>
            <Toggle id={toggleId}>
              <MyComponent onClick={() => dispatch(hideToggle(toggleId))}/>
            </Toggle>
            <button onClick={() => dispatch(showToggle(toggleId))}>Show my component</button>
    </div>
)};
```

Basically, I want to toggle component by its ID because I want to add more components that can be toggled.

Comment: what does state.toggle return ? can you show your combine reducer code ?

Comment: Have you checked with Redux devtools what is the shape of the state after init?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reducer isn't an array so it would break.

If you change your reducer to this does it work?

```
const initialState = [];

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SHOW':
      return {...state, [action.payload]: true};
    case 'HIDE':
      return {...state, [action.payload]: false};
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

and your Toggle component to this:

```
import React from 'react';
import {useSelector} from 'react-redux';


export const Toggle = ({id, children}) => {
  const show = useSelector(state => state[id]);
  return show ? children : null;
};
```

Alternative:

```
const initialState = {
  show_list: [],
  // other state keys
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SHOW':
      let show_list = state.show_list;
      show_list[action.payload] = true;
      return {...state, show_list};
    case 'HIDE':
      let show_list = state.show_list;
      show_list[action.payload] = false;
      return {...state, show_list};
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Toggle component:

```
import React from 'react';
import {useSelector} from 'react-redux';


export const Toggle = ({id, children}) => {
  const show = useSelector(state => state.show_list[id]);
  return show ? children : null;
};
```

Comment: This eliminates the error but state key becomes 'undefined' and child component doesn't show.

Comment: Undefined should still work to hide your component right? Does the toggle button work?

Comment: Oh wait I'm sorry, I misread your action. Remove the `id` part from my version of the reducer.

Comment: it works when initialState is changed to array but then, how can I add other keys for my other states?

Comment: If you need other states we just have to modify it a little bit. I'll edit my answer to show an alternative

Answer (score 0):

Your state does not have any property named `toggles`, rather you are keeping the toggled state directly in `state` object as key/value.

So change

```
const show = useSelector(state => state.toggles[id]);
```

to

```
const show = useSelector(state => state[id]);
```